# Clip text in DisclosureGroup

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a `DisclosureGroup`, which I would like to clip the `Text` label if it is too long, rather than have the `…`. How can I achieve this?

Current code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            DisclosureGroup {
                Text("Content")
            } label: {
                Text("Some long label which is too long for the screen")
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                    // Would likely clip to bounds here, etc...
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar)
    }
}
```

The problem with this attempt is that the disclosure indicator arrow is now off-screen. I would like the width to stay the same, but just clipping the `Text` rather than having it truncated.

| Without `fixedSize` | With `fixedSize` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Without] | [image: With] |

Expected (roughly edited):

[image: Expected]

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Have your tried this ```.minimumScaleFactor(0.5)```?

Comment: @RajaKishan I have added an image of the expected result. I'm not looking to shrink the text - instead I'll fade it out at the end ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68775927/9607863) from yesterday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `overlay` worked.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            DisclosureGroup {
                Text("Content")
            } label: {
                Color.clear
                    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Some long label which is too long for the screen")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                    }
                    .clipped()
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]