# How to erase Path stroke in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drawing

I am trying to erase **Path** stroke by setting **blendMode** modifier, but no luck there  is no clear mode available like in **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext** is **setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.clear)**.

I tried all modes but no luck, it multiply colours producing some new colours of layers.
I think there will be some mechanism available to clear bottom layers colour,
If you know please post the answer.
Thank you.

my code :

```
struct Point : Hashable {
    let x: CGFloat
    let y: CGFloat
    init(_ p:CGPoint) {
       x = p.x
       y = p.y
    }
   func toCGPoint() -> CGPoint {
      CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
   }
}
struct line:Hashable {
    var line:[Point] = []
    var color:Color
    var eraseMode:Bool
}

struct editImage: View {
@State private var eraseMode = false
@State private var lines:[line] = [line(color: .red, eraseMode: false)]
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack{
            Toggle(isOn: $eraseMode) {
                Text("Erase Mode")
            }.padding(.horizontal)
            .onChange(of: eraseMode) {_eraseMode in
                lines[lines.count-1].eraseMode = _eraseMode
            }
            Button(action: {
                lines.removeAll()
                lines.append(line(color: .green, eraseMode: eraseMode))
            }, label: {
                Text("Clear Canvas").padding()
            })
            ZStack{
                ForEach(lines,id:\.self){line in
                    Path{p in
                        var f = true
                        line.line.forEach { point in
                            if f {
                                p.move(to: point.toCGPoint())
                                f = false
                            }else{
                                p.addLine(to: point.toCGPoint())
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }.stroke(line.color,style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 14, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .bevel, miterLimit: 0, dash: [], dashPhase: 0))
                    .blendMode(line.eraseMode ? BlendMode.hue : BlendMode.normal)
                }
            }.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local).onChanged({ v in
                lines[lines.count-1].line.append(.init(v.location))
                
            }).onEnded({ _ in
                lines.append(line(color: .red, eraseMode: eraseMode))
            }))
        }
    }
}
}
```

what i need is in the GIF demo;
[image]

Comment: See my question here, and the answer which uses `mask`. I think that's a similar issue by your description.

Comment: thank you comment, no of link to the question!

Comment: Oops... link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775927/text-opacity-gradient)

Answer (score 0):

You can set blendMode to clear, let see Apple document:

*static var clear: GraphicsContext.BlendMode { get }*

*clear
A mode that clears any pixels that the source image overwrites.*

*With this mode, you can use the source image like an eraser.
This mode implements the equation R = 0 where R is the composite image.*

See code example:

```
enum Mode {
  case draw
  case eraser
}

struct Line {
  var color: Color
  var points: [CGPoint]
  var mode: Mode
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var selectionModeIndex: Int = 0
  @State var lines: [Line] = []
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Picker("Mode:", selection: $selectionModeIndex) {
        Text("Draw mode").tag(0)
        Text("Eraser Mode").tag(1)
      }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
      
      Canvas { context, size in
        for line in lines {
          var path = Path()
          path.addLines(line.points)
          if line.mode == .draw {
            context.blendMode = .normal
            context.stroke(path, with: .color(line.color), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 8))
          } else {
            context.blendMode = .clear
            context.stroke(path, with: .color(line.color), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 8))
          }
        }
      }
      .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ dragValue in
         print("Changed")
        if lines.isEmpty  {
          lines = [Line(color: .brown, points: [dragValue.startLocation], mode: Mode(rawValue: selectionModeIndex)!)]
        } else {
          var newLine = Line(color: .brown, points: [], mode:  Mode(rawValue: selectionModeIndex)!)
          if dragValue.startLocation != lines[lines.count - 1].points.first {
            // Start a new line
            newLine.points = [dragValue.startLocation]
            lines.append(newLine)
            print("Start new point")
          } else {
            print("Change point event")
            let changedValue = dragValue.location
            // Just append point to last line
            lines[lines.count - 1].points.append(changedValue)
          }
        }
      }))
    }
  }
}
```